# Compiler memory consumption with template libraries (boost + Eigen)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, boost, eigen

I am writing a template algorithm that makes use of boost::accumulators and the Eigen linear algebra library.
While compiling, the visual studio compiler (cl.exe), memory consumption peaks at over 2.5GB of RAM, and my PC (windows 7 32 bit with 3GB virtual address space) becomes unresponsive (for quite a long time: ~1 minute). The binary files (.obj) are 10-20MB for these compilation units.

My questions (not directed towards these specific libraries)

1. Is this normal behavior for code that heavily uses templates?
2. Is there something that can be done to reduce the memory demands and
   compile time?
3. If there is no good solution to the problem, why isn't this
   addressed by the people that design the programming language? The
   more people understand C++, the more they are likely to use templates, and generate hard-to compile code, and bloated binaries.

Comment: They make a 32bit Windows 7? and... someone bought it?!

Comment: :) @Dave. Seriously, though, a 64 bit machine would not solve the problem - just allow taking up more memory.

Comment: The "related" question is completely unrelated (it's a runtime issue there, not compiletime). As for your 3: what makes you thing they're not addressing it? Try compiling that same code with a compiler from 5 years ago...

Comment: How could C++ standard committee address problem that arises from implementation of one of the compilers? :)

Comment: @Griwes, are you saying that these problems do not arise in other compilers? (e.g. gcc)

Comment: @killogre Clang has much better memory performance than both GCC and MSVC. So yes, this is compiler dependent. That being said, 10-20 MB object files are huge. Split them up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If there is no good solution to the problem, why isn't this addressed
>   by the people that design the programming language?

Because there is no good solution, *full stop*.

The problem you are talking about has nothing to do with C++. It's an artefact from C- the old "translation unit". Fixing this problem would require re-doing the compilation model. The C++ Committee has been trying for *years* to make this happen without breaking every single line of existing C++ out there (which is a bigger consideration), but it's not a trivial problem. Fixing it would require vast changes.

Also, Clang has *way* better performance, and newer versions of GCC which are variadic-template-equipped can do as well.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I am stuck with VS due to job constraints. Out of curiosity, why do variadic templates reduce the memory load?

Comment: @killogre: I believe that in the process of introducing them, they had to significantly upgrade their compiler infrastructure. VS does not currently have them because implementing them is a big job.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes. Compiling templates is memory consuming. Some implementations suck more than others. In my personal experience, out of GCC, MSVC and Clang, the latter is the best at managing its memory use.
2. You can split your huge source files into several smaller ones. That would even out the load over several compile steps.
3. The people who designed the programming language only cared very little for the implementation, to give compiler writers enough freedom to excel and compete. Or Suck.